# Excel 2010: Last of multiple Application.Intersect fails

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where I monitor for changes in 8 different columns via an If/ElseIf chain and `Application.Intersect` similar to the sample below. Depending on the column, the code is designed to take different actions, such as taking data pasted in and transposing it and pasting only the values or possibly changing the values of other cells in the row.

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, ChangeNum) Is Nothing Then
    ' Do some stuff
ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Target, TransType) Is Nothing Then
    ' Do different stuff
... ' 6 more ElseIf statements
End If
```

Both `ChangeNum` and `TransType` are defined ranges within a specific column same as the other 6 ElseIfs that I did not include.

The problem is that whatever is the last item in the chain of ElseIfs will not trigger or it will not trigger as expected. If I take that exact code and move it up one level in the If/ElseIf tree, it works as expected, but then whatever code it displaced will no longer work correctly.

Is there a limit on the number of links you can have in an If/ElseIf chain in VBA? If yes, what about `Select` statements? If no, does anyone have any thoughts on why the exact same code works so long as it is not the final link in an If/ElseIf chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem will be that the ranges you are checking against may contain cells found in one of the other ones. If you have set the ranges using a statement similar to:

`Set ChangeNum = Range("nameofrange")`

Then the name linked to the range may have been re associated by excel during some of your changes. The easiest way to check this is to go to the **Formulas** tab on the ribbon and select **Name Manager**. Double check that the ranges are all as you expect. If not simply adjust them and your code should begin working as expected.

Comment: That was precisely the problem. I stumbled across it myself at about the same time you were posting your answer. I flipped the order of the last two columns to make sure that no data would even temporarily end up in a monitored column and my code started working as expected.